# Sharing visual studio projects between computers

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I have a laptop and a desktop computer that I wish to share visual studio projects between - what is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Do you need **'version-control'** or **'file synchronization and backup'**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this at the moment is to use Microsoft's new and free TFS (Team Foundation Server) service "in the cloud".

**First**, sign up a TFS account [here](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). You will have to choose a name, which will give you a URL like http://yourname.visualstudio.com/

**Next**, within Visual Studio you can add a TFS server, where you will be able to check-in and check-out your solutions and projects from any number of computers.

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know this existed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to *share* Visual Studio project **(1)** or do you want to *put the project under version-control* **(2)**?

1. For the first case you may consider online backup / storage service like Dropbox, Google Drive or SkyDrive. You will be able to access your project from different computers and could share it with others when needed. It's really the simplest way; no version-control though.
2. If you require version-control I advise you to choose [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org). TFS is like walking the hard and thorny path and is definitely NOT the simplest way.

So, you can install [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) to add SVN as a source control to Visual Studio. Then you can [**"Add the solution to Subversion"**](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/getting-started/) with VisualSVN.

You can either host repositories on your LAN with VisualSVN Server (or any other SVN server) or use a hosted SVN service. Initial setup takes a couple of minutes max actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free SVN service. Here is one provided:- https://www.assembla.com/home